# MapStruct Can Not Build Implementation Code For @Mapping Definition

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mapstruct, mapper

Mapstruct works fine in project but there is a problem with @Mapping annotation.

Working Spring Boot version 2.2.0.RELEASE

Here is dependency details :

```
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct'
annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor'
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0'
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok-mapstruct-binding:0.2.0"
```

Here is example about the problem.

UserEntity.java

```
public class UserEntity {

    private String username;
    private Integer userAge;
    private UserAddressEntity userAddressEntity;
}
```

UserAddressEntity.java

```
public class UserAddressEntity {
    private String userAddress;
    private Integer userPhone;
}
```

UserAddressDTO

```
public class UserAddressDTO {
    private String userAddress;
    private Integer userPhone;
}
```

TargetDTO (I want to convert UserEntity to this DTO)

```
public class TargetDTO {

    private String username;
    private Integer userAge;
    private UserAddressDTO userAddressDto; 
}
```

Here is mapper class :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserEntityMapper  {


    @Mapping(source = "userAddressEntity", target = "userAddressDto")
    List<TargetDTO> fromEntityToDto(List<UserEntity> userEntityList);
}
```

In this interface, Mapstruct can not create implementation for @Mapping. I changed implemenetation like this:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserEntityMapper  {


    @Mapping(source = "userAddressEntity.userAddress", target = "userAddressDto.userAddress")
    @Mapping(source = "userAddressEntity.userPhone", target = "userAddressDto.userPhone")
    List<TargetDTO> fromEntityToDto(List<UserEntity> userEntityList);
}
```

It is still not working.

All other fields are mapping successfully only the definition in @Mapping is not working.

But, when I removed @Mapping and I changed TargetDto like this, it works :

```
public class TargetDTO {
  
    private String username;
    private Integer userAge;
    private UserAddressDTO userAddressEntity; // I just updated property naming
}
```

But why is it not working with @Mapping. **This is the problem.**

Also I tried "uses" definition and seperated problematic mapper but it also could not map UserAddressEntity to UserAddressDTO :

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", **uses = UserAddressMapper.class**)
public interface UserEntityMapper  {


    @Mapping(source = "userAddressEntity", target = "userAddressDto")
    List<TargetDTO> fromEntityToDto(List<UserEntity> userEntityList);
}
```

**What is the problem with @Mapping usage?** When code is compiling Mapstruct can create Implementation class and build implementation code  for all other fields but it can not create implementation code for @Mapping in the Implementation class. I tried many ways and it does not work in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Mapping` is not directly applicable to methods for mapping collections. Instead, you should define a mapping method for individual objects.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserEntityMapper {

  @Mapping(source = "userAddressEntity", target = "userAddressDto")
  TargetDTO fromEntityToDto(UserEntity userEntityList);

  List<TargetDTO> fromEntitiesToDtos(List<UserEntity> userEntityList);
}
```

MapStruct will invoke the `fromEntityToDto` method for each element when performing collection mapping.

Comment: It works! After I have spent all of my day to solve this issue, you saved my another day. Thanks a lot!